# ASP.net Display Image from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image

Solved: I used handlers. Thanks btw.
http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Insert_Images_Database.aspx

How can I display my image inside the DataList1?
I don't have a clear idea of databinding and such. I hope you guys can help. Thanks
This is my code for my ASPX

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        itemID:
        <asp:Label ID="itemIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemID") %>' />
        <br />
        Cloth ID:
        <asp:Label ID="Cloth_IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[Cloth ID]") %>' />
        <br />
        Style:
        <asp:Label ID="StyleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Style") %>' />
        <br />
        Size:
        <asp:Label ID="SizeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Size") %>' />
        <br />
        Color:
        <asp:Label ID="ColorLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Color") %>' />
        <br />
        Image 1:
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("[Image 1]") %>' />
        <br />
        Image 2:
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("[Image 2]") %>' />
        <br />
        Price:
        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />
        <br />
        Notes:
        <asp:Label ID="NotesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' />
        <br />
        Alignment of Image 1:
        <asp:Label ID="Alignment_of_Image_1Label" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("[Alignment of Image 1]") %>' />
        <br />
        Alignment of Image 2:
        <asp:Label ID="Alignment_of_Image_2Label" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("[Alignment of Image 2]") %>' />
            <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TPSConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT CustomizedOrder.userid, CustomizedOrder.itemID, ClothInventory.clothID AS [Cloth ID], ClothInventory.style AS Style, ClothInventory.size AS Size, Color.color AS Color, CustomizedOrder.image1 AS [Image 1], CustomizedOrder.image2 AS [Image 2], CustomizedOrder.itemPrice AS Price, CustomizedOrder.notes AS Notes, Alignment.description AS [Alignment of Image 1], Alignment_1.description AS [Alignment of Image 2] FROM CustomizedOrder INNER JOIN ClothInventory ON CustomizedOrder.clothID = ClothInventory.clothID INNER JOIN Color ON ClothInventory.colorID = Color.colorID INNER JOIN Alignment ON CustomizedOrder.alignment1 = Alignment.alignmentID INNER JOIN Alignment AS Alignment_1 ON CustomizedOrder.alignment2 = Alignment_1.alignmentID WHERE (CustomizedOrder.userid = @userid)">
    <SelectParameters>

    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and this is for the aspx.cs

```
public partial class addtoShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser();
        object UserGUID = User.ProviderUserKey;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("userid", UserGUID.ToString());
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: What datatype is `image1` and `image2`?

Answer (score 0):

Asp:Image.ImageUrl expects an URL value, hence if `Image1` is a string containing the URL of the image your code should work.

On the contrary, if Image1 is the image itself, then you'll need to temporarily [save it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) on the server and provide the Asp:Image control with the URL for the saved file (check [this example](http://geekswithblogs.net/AlsLog/archive/2006/08/03/87032.aspx) for generating the URL)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have image url from database and you have image datatype in your sql then this code will help to [generate image from sql database](http://prakashpatani.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-get-image-from-sql-database.html)!

Answer (score 0):

If image path stored in database: ~/Images/file-name.jpg

=> image url in datalist:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("[ImagePath]") %>' />
```